# ACTION for UIBUTTON in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have one custom class with subclass of UIView, inside this I created one button dynamically.
Now I want to set Action for button method. I set normal like UIviewController.
But its not working.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    but.frame= CGRectMake(200, 15, 15, 15);
    [but setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:but];
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
 }

-(void)aMethod
{

    NextEyeViewController *nexteye=[[NextEyeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextEyeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:nexteye animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`-(void)aMethod` is my method name for button

Comment: In your custom UIView class you might need to enable UserInteraction (it's a property you can set to YES / NO).

Comment: am not using xib there to enable user interaction

Comment: Doesn't matter. If I'm not mistaken, by default `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `NO` for custom UIViews - probably for performance reasons. You have to explicitly set it to `YES` if you want to interact with any controls (buttons, etc...) on your view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an action to your button created programmatically you need to do like this :

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Yes i did this but the thing is am moving from one custom class (UIview) to uiviewcontroller.

Comment: Added please have alook

Comment: So change your selector `@selector(buttonAction)` by `@selector(aMethod)`

Comment: sure you don't pass in aMethod when you click on your button ? Add a breakpoint or a NSLog inside

Answer (score 0):

Create UIButton:

```
UIButton *yourButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameButton];

// Here code to set button properties: color, label...

[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[self.view addSubview:yourButton];
```

Answer (score -1):

Your method has to receive the sender of the action:

```
-(void)aMethod:(id)sender {
   // your code
}
```

Update:
You also have to call your method suitably with `@selector(aMethod:)` instead of `@selector(aMethod)`.

Comment: Anyway, your button passes its identity to your function. You might also have another error, but this is still correct.